# Android - Camera2 createCaptureSession with multiple sizes surfaces

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-mediacodec

How can I use Camera2 and get 2 types of output surfaces at the same time? one of 720X1280 and the other of 1920x1080? I saw I can use the [createCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)) but I did not find any example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer is just provide the captureSession 2 surfaces with the desired sizes. so simple :)